# Pass of user details from Spring security config to Controller Class

Tags: spring-security

Suggestion required after authentication from security config needs to pass the every user details to the APIs request.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is that you can customise your authentication process such that after successful authentication , it will store the user object inside `Authentication` which can be retrieved by calling  `Authentication.getPrincipal()`.

Then in the controller method , you can access the user object representing the current user by :

```java
//You have cast the user to the type of the user that you customzie manually   
MyCustomUser user = (MyCustomUser) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

Or use `@AuthenticationPrincipal` to access it :

```java
@GetMapping("/foo")
public String getFoo(@AuthenticationPrincipal MyCustomUser user) {

    
}
```